# can I get only the updated data from database instead of all the data

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in python 3 I want to get only the updated data from the database. what I mean by that can be explained as follows: the database already has 2 rows of data and I add 2 more rows of data. How can I read only the updated rows instead of total rows

Note: indexing may not help here because the no of rows updating will change.

```
def read_all():
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM CVT")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        # print(rows[-1])
        assert cur.rowcount == len(rows)
        lastrowids = range(cur.lastrowid - cur.rowcount + 1, cur.lastrowid + 1)
        print(lastrowids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert rows "one by one" like that

```py
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (xxxx) VALUES (xxxx)')
```

You then can retrieve the last inserted rows id :

```py
last_inserted_id = cursor.lastrowid
```

**BUT** it will work **ONLY** if you insert a single row with `execute`. It will return `None` if you try to use it after a `executemany`.

If you are trying to get multiple ids of rows that were inserted at the same time [see that answer that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352324/2409641).

Comment: I have tried in the above way(in question) but I am getting an error.                                                                    assert cur.rowcount == len(rows)
AssertionError